# Type D Visa Italy how long can I stay?

Tags: visas, italy

I have a type D long stay visa for Italy. It is a sports visa which was issued on January 18, 2017 and valid until June 30, 2017. The last day of my sports contract is on June 30. My residence permit is for Italy. Before obtaining my visa I needed to provide a return flight itinerary which my team booked for July 11 ( which is in the 6 month period for a long term visa) to bring to my visa appointment before it could be issued.

I fly out of Nice, France if my flight is 11 days past my visa and residence permits validity am I breaking the law even though my flight is out of a different country?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 2):

- The D visa allows you to stay in Italy from January 18th to June 30th. You can also stay in the rest of the Schengen area **as if** you had a C visa for the entire Schengen area valid January 18th to June 30th, which means you can spend at most 90 days out of every 180 in the rest of Schengen.
- Days in Italy between January 18th and June 30th don't count against the 90/180 rule. That might be an issue if you spend much time traveling through Europe, but not if you stay mostly in Italy.
- The 90/180 rule applies to any combination of visa. That is, if you spend 90 days in other Schengen countries between January and June, you cannot stay in France in July

If your nationality needs a visa for short stays, you need a Schengen C visa valid July 1st to July 11th. If you have it, you do **not** have to cross the border at exactly midnight of the 30th.